# Hide <br> when using echo to assign the value of an input php, mysql and html

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, nl2br

Im using nl2br to save inf to a mysql database, it works well but when i use the info in the database as a a value of an input type text it shows `<br>` in every break line, i want to know how to hide the `<br>` and show the space instead

Comment: `$string = str_replace('<br>',' ',$string);`

Comment: Note that when using Anant's suggestion, if you save the value back to the database, it will lose the 'new lines'. (Yeah, I know you said _show the space instead_)

Comment: Use $string = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $string ); if you want line break \n inplace of <br/>.

Comment: @RahulPatel Thanks it worked, every time i show the input (i changed it for a textarea) it show the brakeline, when i show it it seems that there are 2 brakelines but it doenst matter, thank you.